# flex model messe up my content div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been searching for the solution that would solve my problem with having space beneath my footer in Chrome and IE, and then I found solution here [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)  It was a revelation for me :) Now the footer stays nicely on the bottom of the page, but can you tell me why is it messing up my container? You can see this here http://jsfiddle.net/sx2d1t59/3/  and here is the full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/sx2d1t59/3/embedded/result/
The problem seems to be with html, body {height: 100%; } (at least it seems to me). I want my container (and content with it) normally centered in the middle and 1200px wide.

here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="images/someimage.jpg" alt="logo" />
            </div>
            <nav id="main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">BLA BLA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">BLA BLA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="books.html">BLA BLA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="ebooks.html">BLA BLA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="guestbook.html">BLA BLA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">BLA BLA</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            <section id="left-column">
                    <h1>bla bla bla?</h1>

                <p class="text-about">bla bla bla</p>
                <p class="text-about">bla bla bla</p>
                <p class="text-about">bla bla bla</p>
                <p class="text-about">bla bla bla</p>
            </section>
            <section id="right-column">
                <img src="images/some pic.jpg" alt="some pic">
            </section>
        </div>
        <!--- end "content" --->
        <footer>
            <nav id="footer-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="follow-fb">    <a href="#" target="_blank">Follow me on Facebook</a>

            </div>
            <div id="fb-icon">  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/fbicon_thumb.png" alt="Follow me on Facebook" /></a>

            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!--- end "container" --->
</body>`
```

and here is css:

```
html, body  {   height: 100%; }
body        {   display: flex;  }


#container  {   width: 1198px;
                flex: 1;
                border-left: black solid 1px;
                border-right: black solid 1px;
                margin: auto;
            }   


/***************** HEADER ********************/

header  {   background:#000;   
            height: 100px;


        }

#logo   {   width: 114px;
            height: 64px;
            float: left;
            margin-top: 16px;
            margin-left: 40px;
        }
/***************** MAIN NAVIGATION ********************/

#main-nav   {   width:1000px;
                height: 100px;
                text-align:center;
                float: right;



        }



#main-nav  ul   {   height: 100px;
                line-height: 100px;
                width: 1000px;
                float:right;
                display: inline-block:




            }

#main-nav  ul li    {   display:inline-block;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-family: Courier New, Arial, sans-serif;


}



#main-nav a:link {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px;}
#main-nav a:visited {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px;}
#main-nav a:hover {color: #000; background-color: #d66c3c; font-weight: bold;}
#main-nav a:active {color: #000; background-color: #d66c3c; font-weight: bold;}


/***************** CONTENT ********************/

#content {  min-height: 720px;
            overflow: hidden;
}

#left-column    {   width: 600px;
                    float: left;
                    padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px;
                    min-height: 720px;
                    text-align:center;



        }

#right-column   {   width: 500px;
                    float: right;
                    padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px;
                    min-height: 720px;
    }

#right-column img       {   margin-left: 30px;
                            padding:10px;
                            border:3px solid #899298;

                        }


/***************** TITLES AND TEXT ********************/


h1      {   font-size: 60px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Courier New, Arial, sans-serif;
        }


h2      {       font-family: Courier New, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 40px;
                color: #d66c3c;
                margin-top: 50px;
                text-align: center;

        }

h3      {       font-family: Courier New, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 25px;
                margin-top: 50px;
                text-align: center;
        }


.text-about     {   text-align: left;
                    margin-left: 70px;
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-family: Courier New, Arial, sans-serif;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                    margin-top: 15px;
                    line-height: 20px;
                    text-indent: 20px;

                }

.text-contact   {   font-family: Courier New, Arial, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    margin-top: 20px;
                    text-align: center;

                }


/***************** FOOTER ********************/

footer  {   height:100px; 
            background:#000;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding-left: 15px;
            clear: both;
        }

#footer-nav     {   width: 600px;
                    float: left;}

#footer-nav ul  {   display: inline-block;
                    width: 120px;
                    font-family: Courier New, Arial, sans-serif;
                    margin-left: 30px;
                    margin-top: 15px;


                }

#footer-nav li  {   font-size: 18px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    line-height: 35px;

                }                       

#footer-nav a:link {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
#footer-nav a:visited {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
#footer-nav a:hover {color: #d66c3c; }
#footer-nav a:active {color: #d66c3c; } 



#follow-fb  {   float: left;
                width: 250px;
                font-size: 18px;
                text-decoration: none;
                height: 100px;
                line-height: 100px;
                font-family: Courier New, Arial, sans-serif;
                margin-left: 200px;

            }   

#follow-fb a:link {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
#follow-fb a:visited {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
#follow-fb a:hover {color: #d66c3c; }
#follow-fb a:active {color: #d66c3c; }  

#fb-icon    {   float: left;
                width: 48px;
                height: 48px;
                margin-top: 25px;                   
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the height attribute of your body and html.